# How to automatically add my program to gnome panel

Tags: gnome, application

I wrote a program like dropbox seen in pic. I want to add the icon as that of dropbox. How could I do that?

How to automatically do that?

[image]

Comment: I have no gnome insterface available right now but did something like this before: right lick on the menu bar, add a command line execution (not sure about the name). you will have a pop-up where you choose the application to run (command line and parameters) and where you can choose the icon.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like Gnome panel's system tray, so I think you want your application to provide a system tray icon ?

System trays are not specific to Gnome. As a general rule, applications provide an icon by following the [System Tray Protocol Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/latest/). There are many libraries to help you do that. GTK and Qt provide methods to create an icon, for instance in Qt, [the QSystemTrayIcon class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsystemtrayicon.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gnome panel then you can add any application in there. All you have to do is `alt+Right Click` in top gnome panel. Click Add to panel and then select Custom Application Launcher and add your application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found this doc I made once:

> Right click on the task bar and select « Add to Panel... ». Then select « Custom Application Launcher » and click on « Add ».
>
> Enter the informations:
>
> Type: `Application`
>
> Name: `application name`
>
> Command: `the command to start your application`
>
> Comment: `any comment`

[image]

PS: in my comment I said you can choose the icon but it seems not, sorry :/